# Why is the score of the tuned model of mine obviously non-optimal (negative)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to tune a stacking regressor which includes a layer constituting a decision tree, a random forest, and a deep network, and a xgbregressor as a blender.

My tuning procedure below

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
import xgboost

########## Reproducibility
seed_value= 0
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)

########## Data pre-processing
housing = fetch_california_housing()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

########## Models synthesis
def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(48, tf.keras.activations.selu, kernel_initializer="lecun_normal"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(48, tf.keras.activations.selu, kernel_initializer="lecun_normal"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer="lecun_normal"))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["mse"])
    return model

dnn_reg = KerasRegressor(model=build_model())

rnd_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5,
                            min_samples_leaf=1,
                            max_leaf_nodes=9)

rf_reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, max_leaf_nodes=16)

stack_reg = StackingRegressor(estimators=[("rnd", rnd_reg), ("rf", rf_reg), ("dnn", dnn_reg)],
                              final_estimator=xgboost.XGBRegressor())

param_spec = {
    "final_estimator__max_depth": np.arange(1,7).tolist(),
    "final_estimator__learning_rate": np.arange(3e-4, 7e-2).tolist(),
}

stack_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(stack_reg, param_spec, n_jobs=-1, n_iter=10, cv=5, verbose=True)

stack_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(stack_search_cv.best_params_)
print(stack_search_cv.best_score_)
```

reports the following values for the desired hyperparameters

`max_depth: 5, learning_rate: 0.0003`.

However the score of the model is negative. It is weird because the score of the raw model (including all default-valued hyperparameters) is positive. Can one explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your maximum learning rate (0.07) is well below the default (0.3); try increasing it?

Comment: @BenReiniger: Good catch! If you add an answer to the thread, I gladly accept it.